# How to obtain all symbolic solutions this polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have the following $8$ variables, $2$ degree polynomial equations, and was trying to obtain **all** symbolic solutions.
$$
    \begin{cases}
-\sin(a) - \cos(b) \sin(a) - \cos(c) \sin(a) - \cos(d) \sin(a) + \cos(a) \sin(b) + \cos(a) \sin(c) + \cos(a) \sin(d)=0\\
 \cos(b) \sin(a) - \sin(b) - \cos(a) \sin(b) - \cos(c) \sin(b) - \cos(d) \sin(b) + \cos(b) \sin(c) + \cos(b) \sin(d)=0\\
 \cos(c) \sin(a) + \cos(c) \sin(b) - \sin(c) - \cos(a) \sin(c) - \cos(b) \sin(c) - \cos(d) \sin(c) + \cos(c) \sin(d)=0\\
 \cos(d) \sin(a) + \cos(d) \sin(b) + \cos(d) \sin(c) - \sin(d) - \cos(a) \sin(d) - \cos(b) \sin(d) - \cos(c) \sin(d)=0\\
 \sin(a) + \sin(b) + \sin(c) + \sin(d)=0\\
 -1 + \cos(a)^2 + \sin(a)^2=0\\
 -1 + \cos(b)^2 + \sin(b)^2=0\\
 -1 + \cos(c)^2 + \sin(c)^2=0\\
 -1 + \cos(d)^2 + \sin(d)^2=0
\end{cases}
$$
As far as I know, to symbolically solve polynomial equations, there are only two ways, resultants and Grobner basis (am I right?).

So the first thing I tried is to find the Grobner basis of them from Mathematica

(please note that in the following picture, $sa$ denotes $\sin(a)$ and $ca$ denotes $\cos(a)$, and the same for $sb,cb,sc,cc,sd,cd$).

[image]
However, Mathematica stuck on finding roots and I suspect that this is because the degree of the Grobner basis is too high, thus it is not possible to find its roots due to Galois theory (I am not sure whether this is correct). Is there any other ways to find the symbolic solutions?

Thank you so much for any suggestions and comments!

Comment: No problem, give me a minute to copy the equations...is it over the complex numbers, or over integers?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! All variables are real number between $[0,1]$.

Comment: Are those sines and cosines of real angles?  If so they can vary between $-1$ and $1$: note $sb+sd=0$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry. It should be: All variables are real number between [-1,1].

Comment: @Henry Yes, for example $sc$ is $Sin(c)$ actually.

Comment: Please rewrite your system in standard notation, so that we can compute. What is $cc^2$ if not $c^3$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sure! I just rewrote it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I just rewrote it to $Sin$ and $Cos$. Thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but finding the roots of Groebner basis in Mathematica did not give me the answer, I don't know why is that..

Comment: You need to form subcases, so that the Goebner algorithm can easily finish in each subcase. Just putting it to the computer is not enough, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing
$$
\sin(a)=x1, \sin(b)=x2, \sin(c)=x3, \sin(d)=x4,
\cos(a)=x5, \cos(b)=x6, \cos(c)=x7, \cos(d)=x8
$$
we obtain the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
0 & = - x1x6 - x1x7 - x1x8 - x1 + x2x5 + x3x5 + x4x5 \\
0 & = x1x6 - x2x5 - x2x7 - x2x8 - x2 + x3x6 + x4x6 \\
0 & = x1x7 + x2x7 - x3x5 - x3x6 - x3x8 - x3 + 4x7\\
0& = x1x8 + x2x8 + x3x8 - x4x5 - x4x6 - x4x7 - x4\\
0 & =x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 \\
0 & =x1^2 + x5^2 - 1 \\
0 & =x2^2 + x6^2 - 1 \\
0 & = x3^2 + x7^2 - 1\\
0 & = x4^2 + x8^2 - 1
\end{align*}
It has, among other solutions, the real solutions
\begin{align*}
\{0,\ldots ,0\} & =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 - 1,x6 + 1,x7 + 1,x8 + 1\}, \\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 + 1,x6 - 1,x7 + 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 + 1,x6 + 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 + 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 - 1,x6 - 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 + 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 - 1,x6 + 1,x7 - 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 + 1,x6 - 1,x7 - 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 + 1,x6 + 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 - 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 - 1,x6 - 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 - 1,x8 + 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 - 1,x6 + 1,x7 + 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 + 1,x6 - 1,x7 + 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 + 1,x6 + 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 + 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 - 1,x6 - 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 + 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 - 1,x6 + 1,x7 - 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 + 1,x6 - 1,x7 - 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 + 1,x6 + 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 - 1,x8 - 1\},\\
& =\{x1,x5 - 1,x6 - 1,x2,x3,x4,x7 - 1,x8 - 1\},
\end{align*}
Similarly we also get solutions like
$$
\{ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\}
$$
The idea is to split the system into several subcases. I leave this to you (it is possible, but not the best solution).

Comment: I think $sc$ is not $s \times c$ but $\sin(c)$

Comment: Thank you! Does the subcases coming from $x1+x2+x3+x4=0$ and the sum of $Cos^2$ and $Sin^2$ equals to zero? For example, one possible subcase would be: to satisfy $x1+x2+x3+x4=0$, it can be $x1=0, x2=0, x3=0, x4=0$, and since  the sum of $Cos^2$ and $Sin^2$ equals to zero, then we obtain $x5=0, x6=0, x7=0, x8=0$; Another subcase would be $x1=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, x2=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, x3=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, x4=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$; Am I correct?

Comment: However, I found it is hard to ensure all solutions are obtained.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Very good. No, you are not missing something - except that you can learn now, how to do something yourself. I am confident that you can find suitable subcases to solve your problem. I also think that there is another way without using Groebner bases, but this is not your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. My objective of this question is to find **all** symbolic solutions using Groebner basis, however, from $x1+x2+x3+x4=0$, there are actually infinity combinations. Plus, I am interested in how to find **all symbolic solutions**, no matter which method, no necessary Groebner basis. Should I pose a new question or re-edit the current one?

Comment: You can find **all** symbolic solutions by dividing into **finitely many** subcases, like $x_1=0$ or $x_1\neq 0$, or whatever condition you find suitable. Find out, what works for the Groebner system well. I do not think you will get more help from a forum like this (given that someone already has downvoted). So try it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!